# Are there any alternative methods for using SharedArrayBuffer?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-opener-policy

I was attempting to implement a SharedArrayBuffer in my Express app:

```
function setup() {
  try {
    const a = new SharedArrayBuffer(1);
    console.info('SharedArrayBuffer is available.');
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('SharedArrayBuffer is not available.');
  }
}
```

However, I encountered an error: 'SharedArrayBuffer is not available.'

I have added this to my code:

```
const app = new Express();
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy', 'same-origin');
  res.setHeader('Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy', 'require-corp');
  next();
});
```

I have enabled this `Experimental JavaScript shared memory features` while testing.

But still, I am getting the error.

Comment: Node version?  v18.17.0 `SharedArrayBuffer` exists.

Comment: Node version: 16.14.2. Can't I implement `SharedArrayBuffer` in this Node version?

Comment: What do you need a `SharedArrayBuffer` for in an expressjs server? And what does this have to do with cross-origin requests?

Comment: mmm, it says it's been available since 8.10.0,  I assume your calling this at the node side?.. Not the client side Javascript?

Comment: I am exploring the use of SharedArrayBuffer in Express for a specific functionality. It helps with shared memory and concurrent processing in certain scenarios.

Comment: `I have added this to my code:` I fail to see the relevance

Comment: @slow_learner So what is your specific concrete scenario?

Comment: I'm currently working on implementing a feature that requires shared memory capabilities for concurrent processing. SharedArrayBuffer is a potential solution for managing shared memory efficiently in my Express application.

Comment: so why are you sending those headers to the client?

Comment: I'm sending those headers for enhanced cross-origin security in my application.

Comment: what does that have to do with SharedArrayBuffer on the server? Or are you using SharedArrayBuffer in the client? I think I'm confused because you mentioned `express app` I assumed the SharedArrayBuffer was on the server ... is your server in a secure context? i.e. is `window.isSecureCotnext === true`?

Comment: I apologize for any confusion. I'm using SharedArrayBuffer on the client side, and the Express app serves as the backend, ensuring a secure context with implemented security headers. No `window.isSecureContext === true`.

Comment: those headers are required on `top-level documents` - so, I take it those headers are being sent as required. AND you are in a [secure context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts) ? so `window.isSecureCotnext` is `false`?

Comment: Yes, those headers are being sent on top-level documents as required. Regarding the secure context, the correct property is `window.isSecureContext`, and its value is `false` in this scenario.

Comment: You need to either use `localhost` or `https` connection for `isSecureContext`..

Comment: What if I am using `localhost` or `https` and still getting the error?

Comment: At least with the `https`, it should not give you the error. Referring https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74623993/sharedarraybuffer-is-not-defined-error-in-cloud-server-but-working-in-localhos

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'll look into using HTTPS and check if it resolves the issue.